# google actions using actions-on-google nodejs lib v2 unable to create even a simple response

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using google actions with the actions sdk. The backend is a NodeJS environment where I am using this library (actions-on-google).

I got the base conversation working using:

```
gapp.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv, input) => {
  conv.ask('Welcome. What would you like to do today?');
});
```

However, when I try to use any of the rich responses including simpleResponse it gives an error

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: 'Howdy, this is GeekNum. I can tell you fun facts about almost any number, my favorite is 42. What number do you have in mind?',
  text: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any number. What do you have in mind?',
  }));
```

This gives an error: `SimpleResponse is not defined`. I even tried with BasicCard and get a similar error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the error I had made just in case someone else faces it too.

Earlier the `server.js` (using express) was

```
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const gapp = actionssdk({debug: true});
```

with the fulfilment route set as

```
require('./gapp.js')(gapp); // a separate file gapp.js for the code
app.post('/fulfilment', gapp);
```

Reading the docs of the `actions-on-google` npm I noticed that it is mentioned that each of the services and wrappers required must be instantiated. So doing the following worked

```
const {actionssdk, SimpleResponse} = require('actions-on-google');
const gapp = actionssdk({debug: true});
...
require('./gapp.js')(gapp, SimpleResponse); // a separate file gapp.js for the code
app.post('/fulfilment', gapp);
```

Now the gapp module has access to SimpleResponse.